# ajax data returns 'page source code' or 'undefined'

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax, json

I am having problem in AJAX data. (I am using asp.net web forms) i need to collect data from page dom elements, as i want to append their values to a table row asynchronously, in the same page. just to test i wrote alert(data) in success function. But data returns 'source code' or comes as 'undefined'.

Below i tried 2 ways to get data in ajax both HTML and JSON. results are the same.

ajax with JSON dataType:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').live('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var number= $(this).attr('id');
        var date= '06.04.2015';
        var name= "xyz";

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'treatment.aspx',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType:JSON,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                number: number,
                date: date,
                name: name
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            } 
        });
    }); 
});
```

ajax with html dataType:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            url:'treatment.aspx',
            contentType:"text/html",
            dataType: 'html',
            data:"some data",

            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;
            }

        });
```

(I also tried alert(data[0].number) and alert(data.number), not working.)

Thanks.

Comment: what is returned by the service ? Is it a valid JSON ?

Comment: please show us your code on server side as well

Comment: What is the URL to your ajax service? What is the URL of the site on that particular page?

Comment: WHen debugging you really should use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`, as `alert()` actually pauses program execution which means that your debugging act can actually change the performance of your code.

Comment: there is no web service here. i am collecting json data from dom elements in the page. at this statement : var number= $(this).attr('id');var date= '06.04.2015';
        var name= "xyz";

@Cubi

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code i think it might work..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('img').live('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

var jsonObject = new Object();
jsonObject.number = $(this).attr('id');
jsonObject.date   = 'date value';
jsonObject.name   = 'desired name';
var jsonData      = json.parse(jsonObject);

           $.ajax({
url: "your orders",
type: "POST",
data: jsonData,
dataType: "json"
});      
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        } 
    });
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are returning valid json from the server (I suggest that you check this as well).

On your jquery ajax call you have the config

```
dataType: JSON
```

JSON is an object on the window object (IE8+) and not a valid option for the ajax config. So you are passing a javascript object to the jquery ajax call rather than a recognised command; meaning it won't know what to do. You need to change this config property to be

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Details about the correct values for the ajax config options can be found under the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). All of the options for the dataType option are string values.

On a side note - I suggest that you do not use 'live' in jquery as it has been deprecated, instead I recommend using 'on' instead.

EDIT - additional suggestions

It might be an issue with the server side code rather than the jquery. From the aspx page in the ajax url can I assume that you are using Web Forms? If so then an ajax call to an aspx page usually means calling a web method on that page; in this situation the ajax url needs to specify the name of the web method. For example `url: '/some/path/treatment.aspx/MyMethod'` which would have a corresponding web method defined like this in C# (there will be something similar in VB)

```
[WebMethod]
public static string MyMethod(){
    // your code
    return someJsonString;
}
```

I would recommend doing some investigation into what the ajax request is sending and what the server side code is recieving. Perhaps add an error callback on the ajax call and see if it is hit and what it reports back. I would guess that there is some mismatch between what the client is sending and what the server is expecting but without more specific information I am not sure exactly what the problem is.

I hope these suggestions help.

Comment: i do not return json data from elsewhere (like web service). thats what i am confused about. i need to take data from dom elements of page (number, date and name) and append to a table in the same page asyncronously.

Comment: @linda22 I've added some extra suggestions to my answer which may help. Regarding my note about 'live' in jquery - yes it will work at the moment but a future version jquery will remove support for it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited my question and I tried to be more specific.